# Errors occurred during the build.Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'XXX'

Tags: java, eclipse

We are unable to build the workspace in Eclipse Kepler.
It's throwing

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'XXX'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

error while building project.

Even after checking the Eclipse log, we are unable to fix it.
Please find below eclipse log:

```
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'TRi2V3'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dell.toadext.javaeditor.ui.sqlmarker.AstResource.addStringLiteral(AstResource.java:153)
    at com.dell.toadext.javaeditor.ui.nodeResolvers.MethodInvocationResolver.resolveSetLengthBuilderMethod(MethodInvocationResolver.java:151)
    at com.dell.toadext.javaeditor.ui.nodeResolvers.MethodInvocationResolver.resolveBuilderMethod(MethodInvocationResolver.java:100)
.......
```

Could you please suggest the solution to fix it.

Comment: The builder is pointing to a line of code in line 153, which is supposedly in the method addStringLiteral. Seeing the code might actually help a lot.

Comment: This looks like an error in an Eclipse plugin called `com.dell.toadext.javaeditor.ui`. I don't know what that is. The NullPointerException is not in the OP's code.

Comment: It looks like you may be running 'Toad Extension for Eclipse Community' - this is crashing - you should ask them about this.

Comment: Hi greg-449, as per your info, we've un-installed toad related extension in eclipse, now it's building fine.